# Date format based on region in MomentJs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

**Problem**
If a User is in London or some place, then the date format should be **DD/MM/YYYY**
Is it possible using moment ? Can moment format the date based on user's timezone ?

**Note :**  I know we can do it based on user's locale but is it possible using timezone ? Am I going in the right direction ?

**.format('L')** will format it in "DD/MM/YYYY" but it is based on locale not on timezone.

Comment: Since you know that locale != [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) you simply have to map timezones to locales (no built-in moment function for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, I'm not sure you are going in the right direction. Countries can be in the same timezone but have different date formats. Montreal is in the same timezone as New York (Eastern Daylight Time) but as it's in Canada it uses the **YYYY-MM-DD** date format. Using [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) can produce incorrect results, for example:

```js
var montreal = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/Montreal");
var newYork = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
console.log(montreal.format('L')); // This should be '2014-06-01' but produces '06/01/2014'
console.log(newYork.format('L'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue is that locale is not timezone. If you don't use other locales, you will always see `MM/DD/YYYY` since _By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js for later use_ (reference [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/)). In your example, you have to use `en-ca` or `fr-ca` to see results for Montreal.

Comment: Right, yes I see what you're saying. You can derive the correct timezone from a string like "America/Monteral" or "Europe/London" but that will always be insufficient to derive the date format for that location.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) package for that

then you will be able to do as follows -

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

To get the date in specific format you specify that in format() as follows -

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: In this case it will format the date as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSZ"

Comment: You can even use this package to guess the user's timezone (which is not 100% accurate, but might be sufficient in for your partcicular use case): https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/

Comment: @MonikaMangal Thanks but date format should be based on timezone. For eg. If user is in London / France then format should be "DD/MM/YYYY" and if the user is in India then format should be "MM/DD/YYYY". We can not hard-code the format.

Answer (score 1):

A format is not automatically associated with a time zone- but locale.

So, if you want to decide your format based on the time zone, get the time zone with `getTimezoneOffset` and run the result via a predefined constants to get the format you want to apply for a time zone.

```
const zoneFormats = {
   1: "dd/mm/yyyy"
   2: "mm/dd/yyyy"
}
```

Then format your time according the formatter selected via the constant.

```
var format = zoneFormats[new Date().getTimezoneOffset()];
moment().format(format || 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: using format it will format the date in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSZ" but I want it in "DD/MM/YYYY".. 
If we pass **L** in format() then it will format the date in "DD/MM/YYYY" but it works on locale not on timezone